# AJAX Trigger With TextBox Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, triggers, controls

When I put "TextBox" Control with ID "MessageTextBox" in "Triggers" in UpdatePanel with ID "UpdatePanel2", this "TextBox" with ID "MessageTextBox" doesn't want to postback through AJAX. The "Button" Control with ID "MessageButton" work fine, but this TextBox doesn't want to work. Why ?

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <br />

         <asp:TextBox ID="MessageTextBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Height="150px" Width="400px"></asp:TextBox>

    <br />    
        <asp:Button ID="MessageButton" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="MessageButton_Click" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="MessageButton" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="MessageTextBox" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:DataList ID="ChatDataList" runat="server" >
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table style="border:1px solid red">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="lblRaterName" runat="server" Text='<%#      Eval("Text")%>'></asp:Label></td>
                </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>                 
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**When I wrap this "TextBox" Control like this all work but I like more the other way with triggers(the way which is not working like the code above):**

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="MessageTextBox" runat="server" Height="150px" Width="400px"></asp:TextBox>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify `EventName` in your `AsyncPostBackTrigger`:

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="MessageTextBox" EventName="TextChanged" />
```

TextBox will trigger postback *only* when the focus is lost.

Alternatively, you can register your textbox using [ScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerasyncpostbackcontrol.aspx) method on `Page_Load`:

```
ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(MessageTextBox);
```

Or you can even force update panel postback using script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function refreshUpdatePanel() {
            __doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel2.UniqueID %>', '');
        }
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="MessageTextBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Height="150px" Width="400px" onblur="javascript:refreshUpdatePanel()"></asp:TextBox>
```